# How to set default custom messages for all fields in Joi

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

It is possible to set default custom error messages to all fields?

It's quite repetitive setting custom error to individual fields.
This is what I do:

```
const email = Joi
    .string()
    .email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ['com', 'net'] } })
    .required()
    .messages({
        'string.base': `"email" should be a type of 'text'`,
        'string.empty': `"email" cannot be an empty field`,
        'string.min': `"email" should have a minimum length of {#limit}`,
        'any.required': `"email" is a required field`
    });

const password = Joi
    .string()
    .min(8)
    .max(50)
    .required()
    .messages({
        'string.base': `"password" should be a type of 'text'`,
        'string.empty': `"password" cannot be an empty field`,
        'string.min': `"password" should have a minimum length of {#limit}`,
        'any.required': `"password" is a required field`
    });
```

I saw in `Joi` docs that there is a `defaults()` method for setting defaults and I wonder if it's applicable for setting default custom messges.

I'm hoping it could be something like this:

**Example for setting default custom error to fields**

```
const customJoi = Joi.defaults(function (schema) {
    return schema.error((errors) => {
        return errors.map((error) => {
            switch (error.type) {
                case "string.min":
                    return { message: '{#field} exceeded maximum length of {#limit}' };
                case "string.max":
                    return { message: '{#field} should have a minimum length of {#limit}' };
                case "any.empty":
                    return { message: '{#field} cannot be an empty field.' };
                case "any.required":
                    return { message: '{#field} is a required field.' };
                default:
                    return error;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom method for errors.

```
const customMessage = (fieldName, min) => {
   return {
      "string.base": fieldName + "should be a type of text",
      "string.empty": fieldName + " cannot be an empty field",
      "string.min": fieldName + " should have a minimum length of " + min,
      "any.required": fieldName + " is a required field"
   }
};
const email = Joi
               .string()
               .email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ['com', 'net'] } })
               .required()
               .messages(customMessage("email",20));

const password = Joi
                  .string()
                  .min(8)
                  .max(50)
                  .required()
                  .messages(customMessage("password",10));
```